# vim: Per buffer titlestring for 3-way merge (w/Perforce)

Tags: vim, merge, diff, perforce

I want a four pane setup for vim, to do 3-way merging.  I've found I can do this with:

```
gvim.exe -f -d %4 -M %3 %1 %2 -c "wincmd J" -c "set modifiable" -c "set write"
```

But I end up with the 'tmp' files in the title of the base/"theirs" copy.

Perforce can supply me with the path of "theirs" (%T), and I'd like to set "BASE" for base.  How can I override titlestring on a per buffer basis, ideally from the commandline?

Comment: Set `titlestring`.  See `:h 'title'` for details.